# Choose location of command line window

Tags: python-3.x

I'm performing some visual analysis and I need to choose the default coordinate location for the command line window to open to guarantee it is not blocking data on screen.

I'm running Python from Microsoft Visual Studio on a PC. I did find information online for resizing the window:

```
import os

os.system("mode con cols=50 lines=20")
```

but no luck so far in choosing its x,y coords on screen.